# Joining sheets from different excel files into one workbook python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to understand a code that was published a while ago. I couldn't find a proper explanation so I made this post. I'm new to python and If someone could explain me how it works I would really appreciate that. I have marked parts which I don't understand.

[Link to the original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659240/how-to-club-different-excel-files-into-one-workbook-with-different-sheet-names-i/60239698#60239698)

Code itself:

```
    from pandas import ExcelWriter
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

writer = ExcelWriter("output.xlsx")

for filename in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    (_, f_name) = os.path.split(filename) <--- 
    (f_short_name, _) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
    for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names:
        df_excel = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name)
        df_excel.to_excel(writer, f_short_name+'_'+sheet_name, index=False) <---

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mark is just the creator try to name the sheet in a new excel file.

```
(_, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)

# _: 'C:\\Desktop'
#f_name: 'file.xlsx'
```

It returns head and tail of the directory. In this case the tail is file name.

```
df_excel.to_excel(writer, f_short_name+'_'+sheet_name, index=False)
```

This one is to save a dataframe to excel file.
First argument:

- `ExcelWriter` if you want to create an excel file with multiple sheet inside.
- If not, use `file path` (Where do you want to save it).

Second argument : `Sheet name` for each dataframe.

last argument : `index` or the row name

- True : write
- False : skip

for further information:

`os.path.split` : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-split-method/

`.to_excel` : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html