# How can I merge various Excel files into one workbook as separated spreadsheets respecting the format with Python?

Tags: python, excel, spreadsheet

I have tried to merge several Excel files into one workbook with Python and I have only found different methods that only merge all the data into one sheet.

What I need to do is to merge all the Excel files from the current directory subfolders into one workbook, but adding each sheet of each Excel file as a separated worksheet.

If anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

*UPDATE* I have tried the solution with Pandas you showed to me in the comments, but the bad thing about it is that it does not respect format like, for example, cell color, font type, box size and border, and so on. This is very important because it is the format that the client uses, so I cannot ignore it, but thank you for the answer!

Is there any workaround with Pandas, Pywin32 or any other Excel library, for example?

Comment: It seems the question was asked in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659240/how-to-club-different-excel-files-into-one-workbook-with-different-sheet-names-i can you try?

Comment: @KennyTaiHuynh that solution worked but it stripped all the formatting from the original files, and I would need to respect it. I updated the question.